# jquery shake effect and margin-auto

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, shake

Having a spot of bother with this...
[shake effect example](http://jsfiddle.net/PHPsycho/mwVkm/1/)

in firefox if I omit the line

```
$this.css({'margin-left':$this.position().left});
```

then the box is animated over to the left instead of in the centre. If I keep that line of code to fix firefox then chrome has the same problem.

Any tips on getting round this would be grand.

thanks in advance

Comment: In both browsers see what value, or result, returned by `var val = $this.position().left;` and, assuming they're different (I'm on iPhone and away from desk), use an `if` to test for those values, and include, or omit, the line causing the problem as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution (not a happy one but it 'works' cross browser - I say cross browser, got ie9 and my work machine can't run virtual PC!!!!);

```
var options = {
              direction: 'left',
              distance: 10,
              times: 2
              };
var left = $this.position().left > parseInt($this.css('margin-left')) ? $this.position().left : $this.css('margin-left');
$this
    .css({'margin-left': left})
    .effect('shake' , options , 75 , function(){
        $this.removeAttr('style');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to introduce an additional inner div to shake. For example, if the div you want to shake (and that has "margin 0 auto") has the id "centered", then do not shake this div, but add an inner div "shake" and shake that div.

```
<div id="centered">
    <div id="shake">
        <div>the content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yAjHa/

Answer (score 0):

You can detect Firefox or Chrome with `$.browser` in jQuery.

You could then decide whether or not to apply that CSS.

Comment: I could but $.browser is deprecated so I'd really like a solution that is browser agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Think i got what you were asking, is this it?

http://jsfiddle.net/mwVkm/3/

> Please bring the answer you're demonstrating in-line with the answer here. JS Fiddle is a resource for demonstration, not somewhere to host the whole of the answer. – [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas) 20 mins ago

As per the above comment here is what i changed:

jQuery:

`$this.css({'margin-left':$this.position().center});`

CSS - Made some tweeks to the containing `<div>`:

`#box{ width: 20px; height: 20px; margin:auto auto;}`

Hope that helps?

Comment: Please bring the answer you're demonstrating in-line with the answer **here**. JS Fiddle is a resource for demonstration, not somewhere to host the whole of the answer.

Comment: [David Thomas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas): done, was being a bit lazy. Only just discovered jsfiddle so im using it loads.