# jQuery for shaking text within a textbox

Tags: jquery, textbox, shake

I would like to provide shake effect for the text inside a textbox when the validation fails. Can some one suggest the jQuery code for the same.

Here's a link that shows the exact requirement. [Click here](https://www.slideshare.net/signup/)

Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090156/jquery-shake-effect-and-margin-auto?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be doing something like

```
function shakeText(selector){
    $(selector).animate({'padding-left' : '5'} , 1000 , function(){
        $(selector).animate({'padding-left' : '0'} , 1000)}
);

}
shakeText('#element')
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDaA4/)

Comment: instead of padding, margin would give a more desirable effect like the link mentioned in the question

Comment: hey codeiz, this sounds to be the right code. When the width of textbox is also set, it is perfect....  thanks a lot bro...

Comment: hi @MandeepJain, margins appear to give added effects to the field... lemme thank you for your response..